# Expand div to specific height depending on amount of text

Tags: javascript, css

I have set the height of a div to a specific value I.E 60px. I want the height of the div to expand to 80px and 100px depending on the amount of text in the div. I have tried to do this a few ways but as of yet haven't found a solution.

Here is my code.

```
  HTML
       <div id="header">
                <div class="header-text">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Text goes here, Text goes here, Text goes here,  </h3>
                    <h6 id="support-text">supporting text</h6>
    
    
                </div>
                   
        CSS
        #header {
        height: 60px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #f4f6f8;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 0px 20px;
        
    }
    
    Javascript
    
    function increase() {
        var text = parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.height);
        if (text < 80) {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "60px";
        } else if (text == 80) {
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "80px";
        } else if (text > 80){
            document.getElementById("header").style.height = "100px";
    }
    
    increase();
```

Comment: minHeight and maxHeight styles?

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    const div = document.querySelector('#test'),
        divHeight = div.offsetHeight;

    if (divHeight === 72) {
        div.style.height = '100px';
    }
</script>
```

variables and value are just placeholders, you can change it.

Comment: This works to a certain extent. I want the div to expand automatically depending on the amount of text however i still currently have to manually set the height?

Comment: I was referencing your approach that is why. BUT if you want the height of a div to expand depending on the amount of text, remove the `height` and use `minHeight = 60px` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> `parseInt(document.getElementById("header").style.height)`

The style height of your element will be exactly whatever you set it to. For example `"60px"`.

If you want to find the actual height of the div, instead of `.style.height` use `.clientHeight`.

If the text goes beyond the height of the div, you can use `.scrollHeight` to get the full height of the content.